# Adding an extra parameter to eloquent relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

This is a weird implementation that I am trying to do in `eloquent`.

So the concept here is:

I am trying to create a dynamic `relation` for a `product` and `product instance`.

`Category` has multiple `products`. `Products` have multiple types. I decided to create multiple `product types` depending on what the product is for.

For eg: There can be `Food` and `Clothes`. Food is a different class and has properties totally different for it. There are other things that I need to differentiate for food and clothes.

I obviously have two different tables for these but a single category table that has `product type slug` to differentiate which category is for which `product`.

There is a `Product` class that has general description, slugs etc. everything that a general product has. The Food and the Clothes class are for instance of these products with specific details for the particular instance

I have defined `relation` of `product` and `product instance` like this.

```
function instance( $productInstance ) {
    return $this->hasMany( get_class( $productInstance) );
}
```

I can get relation like this. `$product->instance( $instance )->get()`;, gives me the exact `relation` that I need, based on what class instance I pass in the relation.

This worked very smoothly. Until I needed to load `multiple relations`

This is where I am stuck.

I cannot pass the the model in the instance in with function to eager load or load function to lazy load relation. This function does not work as relation

```
$category->with(['subCategory.products' => function( $q ) use ($productModel ) {
        $q->with( 'instance' );
    }])->get();
```

I cannot pass the `instanceModel` class to tell the `relation` what `table` to fetch from.

Is there a way that I can pass the `modelInstance` so that I can get the two level `relation` loaded into `subCategory`
Or a different implementation of this?
Any Suggestions??

Comment: Have you looked at polymorphic relations? It sounds like what you are trying to achieve. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: I have implemented that in the lower levels like product orders but because there are different table that it relates to in this level.